# VBA post request on a website API with parameters

Tags: html, vba, post, parameters, request

I wanted to retrieve the different prices given by then kraken API but i'm not very familiar with the construction of POST requests.

I retrieve a code which could make the request but without any parameters:

```
Sub retrieve_price()
Const sUrl As String = "https://api.kraken.com/0/public/Ticker"

Dim oRequest As WinHttp.WinHttpRequest
Dim sResult As String

Set oRequest = New WinHttp.WinHttpRequest
With oRequest
    .Open "POST", sUrl, True
    .Send 
    .WaitForResponse
    sResult = .ResponseText
End With

Range("A1") = sResult


End Sub
```

[kraken API information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c0Y7w.png)

From the kraken API information they write:

```
Get ticker information
URL: https://api.kraken.com/0/public/Ticker

Input:

pair = comma delimited list of asset pairs to get info on
```

(same as enclosed picture or on https://www.kraken.com/help/api#public-market-data)

However to add this parameter i tried both:

In my with add:

```
.SetRequestHeader "pair", "ETHEUR"
```

and also:

```
.SetRequestHeader "Content-Type", "pair=ETHEUR"
```

or instead write for my send:

```
.Send ("pair=ETHEUR")
```

but both ways didn't work and i don't know how i should proceed then.
I read [How are parameters sent in an HTTP POST request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14551194/how-are-parameters-sent-in-an-http-post-request) 
But i didn't understand how to apply what was written on the post
Could someone give me a piece of advice about it?
Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want a `GET` request.

If you type the following into a Web Browser:

`https://api.kraken.com/0/public/Ticker?pair=ETHEUR`

You should get a response something like this:

```
{"error":[],"result":{"XETHZEUR":{"a":["167.71714","1","1.000"],"b":
["167.65000","200","200.000"],"c":["167.71822","0.25164886"],"v":
["351548.13416062","386545.69665419"],"p":["169.62204","170.24439"],"t": 
[50582,55183],"l":["151.00995","151.00995"],"h":
["190.98999","190.98999"],"o":"181.57867"}}}
```

You should be able this parse this JSON response to get at what you need.

Comment: Indeed, i didn't know it would be just this simple. Thank you very much!